# Select query changing content order

Tags: sql, db2

I am using DB2 db, I have a table with one column containing xml, when I view the table in the data view of SQL Developer

```
<ns5:benefitComponent desc="Urgent Care Professional" level="2" name="UrgentCareProfessional">
```

now when i use a select query to fetch this, it changes to

```
<ns5:benefitComponent name="Acupuncture" level="1" desc="Acupuncture">
```

The order of the attributes changed am not sure why this happens, can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

DB2 stores an XML in a internal format, but it is stored according to the XML schema. Probably, your XML schema does not enforce an order. You should define the elements in a sequence in order to force the order.

http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_sequence.asp